# Python high-order functions

Tags: python, functional-programming

Given the following code, i cant understand why f and fib behaves differently.
the example taken from Barkley cs61a course

```
def fib(n):
    if n==1 or n==0:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def decor(f):
    def counted(*args):
        counted.call_count += 1
        return f(*args)
    counted.call_count = 0
    return counted
```

when i load the code into the interpreter i got this output:

```
>>> fib(6)
8
>>> f = decor(fib)
>>> fib = decor(fib)
>>> # f and fib are both vars that represents a decorated fib function

>>> f(6)
8
>>> f.call_count # why 1 ???
1
>>> 
>>> fib(6)
8
>>> fib.call_count # 49 calls, that's fine
49
```

Answer (score 2):

`f.call_count` is 1 because `f` calls `fib`, and then `fib` recursively calls itself to calculate the result. In this whole procedure, `f` is only called once.

But when you do `fib = decor(fib)`, you're overwriting the `fib` function in the global scope, so from that moment on `fib` will recursively call the *decorated* `fib`.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `fib` and then `f` calls `fib` instead of itself:

```
def fib(n):
    if n==1 or n==0:
        return n
    else:
        print("fib is: " + repr(fib))
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def decor(f):
    def counted(*args):
        counted.call_count += 1
        return f(*args)
    counted.call_count = 0
    return counted



f = decor(fib)
fib = decor(fib)

print("=== f ===")
print(f(6))
print(f.call_count)

print("=== fib ===")
print(fib(6))
print(fib.call_count)
```

When I run this the output is:

```
=== f ===
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
8
1
=== fib ===
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
fib is: <function counted at 0x7fa844639758>
8
49
```

Note that `fib is` function at `0x7fa844639758` all the time.

Comment: is it means that fib is the same at the global scope ? i assume binding fib again to decor(fib) returns a new function which is not related to the 'old' fib, exactly as f does.... is it something specific to python ? make me think i miss some basic language understanding. seems obvious that rebind fib should return same as f